# How to debug outlook addin in windows desktop app?

Tags: outlook, outlook-web-addins

I have created an outlook addin. we can debug the app easily in the browser. but it's difficult do the same in desktop apps. In mac, we have this command

```
defaults write com.microsoft.Word OfficeWebAddinDeveloperExtras -bool true
```

by running this we can inspect the addin. Is there some way to do it in the windows desktop app as well?

Comment: Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-using-f12-developer-tools-on-windows-10

Comment: This is for the browser. In browser, I know how to debug that. But I want a similar thing to do for outlook app in windows.